# Autocomplete.js Suggestions?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, autocomplete

I have an autocomplete plug-in ([DevBridge AutoComplete](https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete/blob/master/readme.md)) on my text box.

```
$('#myTextBox').autocomplete({
    serviceUrl: '/Handler/Autocomplete.ashx?'
});
```

It is making the Ajax call (I can see the JSON return in Fiddler),  and I am getting a return like this:

```
[{"Key":39,"Value":"118"},{"Key":40,"Value":"155"},{"Key":2,"Value":"16"}]
```

but I keep getting an error:

```
Unable to get property 'length' of undefined or null reference
```

On this part of the code:

```
verifySuggestionsFormat: function (suggestions) {
        // If suggestions is string array, convert them to supported format:
        if (suggestions.length && typeof suggestions[0] === 'string') {
            return $.map(suggestions, function (value) {
                return { value: value, data: null };
            });
        }

        return suggestions;
    }
```

I'm not sure what this means. Can someone tell me how to fix this? Is it just syntax? I'm not sure where/how to add these suggestions...

Comment: if you try to `console.log` it, the result is ?

Comment: `console.log` which? length? It is 0...

Comment: `console.log` suggestions at the top of your `verifySuggestionsFormat` function

Comment: I delete questions that I have found answers to my self and the incorrect answer is given by others to the question.

Comment: @BarryTormey You know you can post and accept your own answers, right?

Answer (score 0):

`suggestions` is null or undefined.

Before inspecting the variable, test that it exists:

```
if (!suggestions) return;
```

For example:

```
verifySuggestionsFormat: function (suggestions) {

    // Fail fast if suggestions is not valid
    if (!suggestions) return;

    // If suggestions is string array, convert them to supported format:
    if (suggestions.length && typeof suggestions[0] === 'string') {
        return $.map(suggestions, function (value) {
            return { value: value, data: null };
        });
    }

    return suggestions;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps my question was worded poorly. I know that suggestions is null or undefined, but it should be populated, and I can not figure out why. Suggestion should have some length, I'm just not sure how to get that value to it.